# Replacement for php-auth and php-auth-http on 18.04 (Bionic Beaver)

Tags: 18.04, php7

In Ubuntu 18.04 the two packages

- php-auth
- php-auth-http

disappeared.

Is there any replacement for them, i.e. do they just have a different name or where did they go.

I am trying to upgrade an application from 14.04 with PHP 5 to 18.04 with PHP 7.2 and I am suffering from an HTTP 500 error where I am quite sure this is because of those missing packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

php-auth and php-auth-http in ubuntu 14.04 are essentially prepackaged PEAR package. In order to get this installed in Ubuntu 18.04, you need to install php-pear

```
sudo apt install php-pear
```

and then install the auth package using

```
sudo pear install Auth
```

or

```
sudo pear install Auth_HTTP
```

for the Auth_HTTP package